# Is there any way track a Andriod phone using IMEI Number

Tags: android, phone, geolocation

I have lost my phone and I have a IMEI number of it. However, the guy removed my SIM card.

Is there any way to track who is using my phone?

Comment: That's something for your phone company to tackle.

Comment: The IMEI is sent every time a mobile initially connects to a mobile network. I think only Vodafone offers to block IMEIs.

Comment: Is there something specific to the Android in your question? Back tracking functions?

Answer (score 1):

Your service provider has a registry with every customer and latest cell id they have visited. In this case the location accuracy depends on the density of cells, usually the radius is something in range of 300-1000 meters. Combining several records, you can triangulate the device location quite accurately.

If the SIM-card is removed and the phone was taken to another network, a.k.a roaming, the location information is only stored by the other service provider. If the sim-card would be in place, the location data would be relayed back to your service provider.

Usually service providers are not interested to give out location data in these cases. It may violate some legistlation, as you could effectively track some other person than yourself, by placing your cell phone into his/hers car etc.. It may also be time consuming for them to dig the databases, so they usually give out this infomation only when requested by the police.

If you happen to remember the MAC address of your phone WiFi-adapter, you could check the DHCP-tables of access points in your area. In the best case, you have some firewall/IDS logs with timestamps. In the best case this will save your day, pinpointing when the device was last seen in the network, even revealing sites visited from the stolen device.